# Записывать пары элементов(положительно+отрицательно) в массив с++

Tags: c++, массивы

Мне нужно пройтись по массиву и найти пары элементов положительно + отрицательно и записать их во второй массив. Между каждой парой записывать 0.

```
int arr_2[length];

cout << "Задача 2. \n";
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (arr1[i] > 0 && arr1[i+1] < 0 ){
            arr_2[i] = arr1[i];

            cout << arr_2[i] << " ";
        }
}
```

Comment: А где волшебное слово "и быстро!"?... *"Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу"*

Comment: Я еще новый, не в курсе. Я записываю при проверке только один положительный элемент, я не знаю, как записывать следующий после него элемент и добавлять еще 0.

Comment: @k3rnelpan1c так а что у вас все таки трудность вызвало? Добавление элемента в массив?

Comment: @ Andrej Levkovitch как мне добавлять по два элемента последовательно, еще и разделяя их нулём?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ладно, просто чтоб не висело... Не компилировал, просто набросок.

```
int arr_2[length/2*3]; // Массив нужен побольше. Конечно, лучше бы все же вектор...

cout << "Задача 2. \n";
int k = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (arr1[i] > 0 && arr1[i+1] < 0 ){
            arr_2[k++] = arr1[i];
            arr_2[k++] = 0;
            arr_2[k++] = arr1[++i];
        }
}
```

После этого в `k` - количество элементов в массиве `arr_2`.